# How to pass value to the controller?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to pass value to the child controller from the `stateProvider` from Angular.

I have something like

```
  $stateProvider      
        .state('test', {
            url: '/test',
            views: {
                '': {
                    templateUrl: 'test.html',
                    controller: 'testCtrl',
                    testValue : true
                }
            }
        })
```

I want to pass a testValue variable to the testCtrl from here. My codes above don't really work. Can someone help me about it? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is also a `data` property that you can use instead of resolve. See documentation here https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Nested-States-%26-Nested-Views#inherited-custom-data

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
 $stateProvider      
    .state('test', {
        url: '/test',
        views: {
            '': {
                templateUrl: 'test.html',
                controller: 'testCtrl',
            }
        },
        resolve : {
           testValue : function()
           {
             return {value : true}
           }
        }
    })
```

And in testController:

```
function testController($scope,........,testValue){
   $scope.value = testValue.value;
}
```

More info [here](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#resolve)